# Navigating vim editor

Tags: vim, editor

Which command would you use to swap the words hither and yon on any
line with any number of words between them? (You need not worry about
special punctuation, just uppercase and lowercase letters and spaces.)

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at theses two plugins:

1. Neovim: https://github.com/gbprod/substitute.nvim
2. Vim: https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange